# Finding $\sum\limits_{n=1}^r {3(3n-2)(-2)^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find $\sum\limits_{n=1}^r 3(3 n - 2) (-2)^{n - 1}$.

This is a [JEE](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination&ved=0ahUKEwi_6anEl4nWAhWDsI8KHQq8C7gQFggnMAA&usg=AFQjCNFnXnHCORX5FCVb-Ov2CkwIWVEsMA) level question where it has been asked to find the summation till 8th term of the series $1.3 -4.6 +7.12 -\dotsb.$

Though, it can be calculated arithmetically but just for giving justice to mathematics I tried to put it in an equation. After giving few shots and baffled I decided to seek here for help.

I'm not sure if any solution can be synthesized to find the summation till $r$-th term explicitly. Drop whatsoever below!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: try this here $$\frac{1}{3} \left(-3 (-2)^r r+(-2)^r-1\right)$$

Comment: Hints: (a) consider the sum of an arithmetic series $an+an^2+...+an^r$ and (b) consider its derivative with respect to $n$

Comment: actually I directly copy pasted the expression from Wolfram...well, updated!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner "try this here" Another useless comment.

Comment: aha then make a better comment

Comment: Is the question about $$(-2)^{n - 1}$$ or about $$\left(-\frac12\right)^{n - 1}\ ?$$ I am asking because your post mentions $$1.3 -4.12 +7.24 -...$$ which is irrelevant to the sum as written at present.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $$S_r(x)=\sum_{n=1}^r(3n-2)x^{3n-3}$$ is $$S_r(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^rx^{3n-2}=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{r-1}x\cdot x^{3n}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{1-x^{3r}}{1-x^3}\right)$$ hence $$S_r(x)=\frac{1-(3r+1)x^{3r}}{1-x^3}+3x^3\frac{1-x^{3r}}{(1-x^3)^2}$$ Now, your sum is $3S_r(x)$ for any $x$ such that $x^3=-2$, and then $$S_r(x)=\frac{1-(3r+1)(-2)^r}{1-(-2)}+3(-2)\frac{1-(-2)^r}{(1-(-2))^2}=\frac13\left(1-(3r+1)(-2)^r-2(1-(-2)^r)\right)$$ that is finally,

> $$\sum_{n=1}^r 3(3 n - 2) (-2)^{n - 1}=3S_r(x)=-1-(3r-1)(-2)^r$$

For $r=8$, the sum is $$-5889$$

Comment: Please stop modifying the question...

Comment: Woopsie..those were subtle changes...

Comment: @Did beautifull thinkings as always..

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{r-1}(3n+1)(-2)^n&=3\sum_{n=0}^{r-1}n(-2)^n + \sum_{n=0}^{r-1}(-2)^n\\
&=3\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}n(-2)^n + \frac{1-(-2)^r}{3}\\
&=3\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}\left((-2)^n \sum_{j=0}^{r-1-n}(-2)^j\right) + \frac{1-(-2)^r}{3}\\
&=3\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}\left((-2)^n\frac{1-(-2)^{r-n}}{3}\right) + \frac{1-(-2)^r}{3}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}\left((-2)^n(1-(-2)^{r-n})\right) + \frac{1-(-2)^r}{3}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}(-2)^n-\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}(-2)^{r} + \frac{1-(-2)^r}{3}\\
&=(-2)\frac{1-(-2)^{r-1}}{3}-(r-1)(-2)^{r} + \frac{1-(-2)^r}{3}\\
&=\frac{-1-2(-2)^{r}}{3}-(r-1)(-2)^{r}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$3\sum _{n=1}^r \left(3 (-2)^{n-1} n+(-2)^n\right)=3\sum _{n=1}^r (-2)^n+3\sum _{n=1}^r  n(-2)^{n-1}$

The first is the sum of a geometric progression and gives $\dfrac{(-2)^{r+1}-1}{-2-1}-1=\dfrac{2}{3} \left((-2)^r-1\right)$

For the second sum $\sum _{n=1}^r  n(-2)^{n-1}$

consider

$1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots+rx^{r-1}\quad(*)$

if we integrate each term we get

$x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots+x^r=\dfrac{x^{r+1}-1}{x-1}-1=\dfrac{x \left(x^r-1\right)}{x-1}$

if we take the derivative of this result, we find the sum of $(*)$

$1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots+rx^{r-1}=\dfrac{(r (x-1)-1) x^r+1}{(x-1)^2}$

therefore plugging $x=-2$ we get

$\sum _{n=1}^r  n(-2)^{n-1}=\dfrac{1}{9} \left(1-(-2)^r (3 r+1)\right)$

and in the end we have

$3\sum\limits_{n=1}^r (3 n - 2) (-2)^{n - 1}=2 \left((-2)^r-1\right)+\left(1-(-2)^r (3 r+1)\right)=-3 (-2)^r r+(-2)^r-1$

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

Alternative solution: Add $S_r$ to $2S_r$:
$$S_r=1\cdot 3- 4\cdot 6+7\cdot 12-10\cdot 24+\cdots +3(3r-2)(-2)^{r-1}$$
$$2S_r= \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1\cdot6-4\cdot 12+7\cdot 24-\cdots -3(3r-5)(-2)^{r-1}+6(3r-2)(-2)^{r-1} $$
$$3S_r=1\cdot 3-3\cdot 6+3\cdot 12-3\cdot 24+\cdots +3\cdot 3(-2)^{r-1} \Rightarrow $$
$$3S_r=1\cdot 3-3\cdot 6(1-2+4-\cdots +(-2)^{r-2})+6(3r-2)(-2)^{r-1} \Rightarrow $$
$$3S_r=1\cdot 3-18\cdot \frac{(-2)^{r-1}-1}{-2-1}+6(3r-2)(-2)^{r-1} \Rightarrow $$
$$S_r=1+2((-2)^{r-1}-1)+2(3r-2)(-2)^{r-1} $$
$$S_r=1-(-2)^r-2-3r(-2)^r+2(-2)^r \Rightarrow $$
$$S_r=-1-3r(-2)^r+(-2)^r.$$

Answer (score -1):

There indeed is an expression:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^r 3(3n-2)(2^{-n}) = 12 - 2^{-r} (9r+12)$$

This can be derived by letting $r \to \infty$ to determine the limiting value of the sum, then trying to determine the successive differences.

Comment: Limiting value of summation of Divergent series is a bad news..

Comment: @user477126 this is a convergent series.

Comment: You deal with $$2^{-n}$$ instead of $$3(-2)^{n-1}$$

Comment: @user477126 This series is convergent, not divergent. To see this, you have to note that $\frac{n}{2^n}$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ since $2^n$ grows far more rapidly than $n$, so the expression $\frac{n}{2^n}$ is convergent. SImilarly, the rest of the expression can be seen to be convergent, so we are done showing it is convergent.

Comment: Oh, dammit, didn't read the qeustion properly. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to rectify my mistake.

Comment: Oh! I think I am guilty of miscommunication....but that's $2^(n-1)$ rather $\frac{n}{2^n}$